# AMP pages show blank pages

Tags: amp-html

I'm trying to resolve a problem with AMP implementation for my website.

As you can see below all my AMP pages are now availabled on google mobile searchs :

[image: AMP Carroussel]

My problem is that each time I click on AMP page link, I obtain a blank page as below :

[image: AMP Blan page]

But if I open the link **in a new tab, the page is well displayed**.

It's really strange especially because all my pages are well validated by Google AMP validator and the page is loaded correctly by the google AMP cache : https://cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/amp.argentdubeurre.com/promotions-reductions/enfant/puericulture/6691-rose-ou-bleu-grand-destockage-puericulture-70.html

To have the problem, you have to follow these steps :

1. Use google AMP searchs on your mobile : [google AMP Searchs](https://www.google.fr/webhp?esrch=AcceleratedMobilePages::Preview,AcceleratedMobilePagesDesktop::Promo&gws_rd=cr&ei=zmSwV4nkMMeeaKDViegP)
2. Enter for example : argentdubeurre+rose ou bleu
3. Click on AMP link, you should have blank page. Now if you click on "open in new tab", it should be OK.

Do you have an idea to help me to solve this problem ?

I'm trying to find a solution without success.

Comment: Maybe something on your site (plugin/extension) is adding extra content and breaking the output of the main AMP script (and also breaking the page). Check this [related thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/amp-showing-blank-page). Also try to clear your cache if used on site plugin or CDN.

Comment: Thanks for your advices. I have deleted all javascript ressources not really needed and defined the simplest AMP page structure. I will have a look on in few days to check if I have still the same problem. Tkanks for your help.

Comment: Just to inform you that after few days and new tests, the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to let you know that someone gives me the solution to solve this problem on another help forum.

Indeed in CSS I had a row which defined the position for html tag :

```
html{position:relative}
```

There is just to remove it or to set the html's position to static.

As explained by Andrea on Google Webmaster Central Help Forum :

> The reason is that when accessed from google's cdn a script sets the body tag as absolutely positioned. This takes it out of the page flow, so it is not used in order to compute the height of the ancestor. I believed that elements that had a relative positioning behaved like static elements if not moved, but this is evidently false in this specific case and as a consequence the html loses the height

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause is that your images block attempts to load them directly. The following URLs referenced in: https://amp.argentdubeurre.com/promotions-reductions/enfant/puericulture/6691-rose-ou-bleu-grand-destockage-puericulture-70.html return a 403 when I attempt to load them directly:
- https://img.argentdubeurre.com/content/6691/illustration/destockage-rose-bleu-4.jpg
- https://img.argentdubeurre.com/design/logo/Logo_ADB_200.jpg

Comment: Thanks for this feedback. Changes have been done. Now images are well displayed without 403, but the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, might have just needed a bit of time to cache all of your pages.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It's very strange because I have tested on several phones and I have also blank pages. And my AMP pages are online since few weeks.

Comment: Strange, I tried to take a look at it again on my phone this time but it wouldn't bring up the carousel.

Comment: I don't know why some days I have AMP pages with caroussel in google results and some days no. To be sure that I don't have an external ressource which blocked AMP script, I have defined the simplest AMP structure. I have deleted amp iframe, amp analytics... I will have a look on in some days to check if I have still the same problem. Thanks again for your help